# Create and Unit test an Util class

Tags: spring, hibernate, unit-testing

In my application I need to make advanced search against an equipements database, so i created this function in my service interface:

`public List<Equipement> findByCriterias(SearchEquipement searchEquipement) ;`

I thought that the best way to implement this function is, since I'm working with Spring MVC and Hibernate, to add a function to my DAO interface:

`public List<Equipement> getByCriteria(org.hibernate.Criteria criteria) ;`

in order to accomplish her mission the `findByCriterias` method needs to transform the `searchEquipement` to a `org.hibernate.Criteria`, so i decided to create an util class to do this (not complete yet) :

```
public class ApplicationUtil {

private ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("mmapp/util/application-context-util.xml") ;

private SessionFactory sessionFactory ;

public void setSessionFactory(){
    sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) context.getBean("sessionFactory") ;
}

public synchronized Criteria changeSearchEquipementToCriteria(SearchEquipementsearchEquipement) {
    setSessionFactory() ;
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Equipement.class) ;
    return criteria ;
}
}
```

the problem is when i tried to unit test this part, i have many troubles.

```
public class ApplicationUtilUnitTests {

    @Test
    public void testChangeSearchEquipementToCriteria(){
        ApplicationUtil util = new ApplicationUtil() ;
        Criteria criteria = util.changeSearchEquipementToCriteria(null) ;
        assertNotNull(criteria) ;
    }
}
```

that's after several other tries, now i get this error:
`org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answer lies in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400598/248082). You're mixing *Integration Testing* with *Unit Testing*. By nature of your requirement what you can do is:

- Use a mocking API such Mockito, PowerMock, EasyMock, or any one that suits you
- Mock Hibernate's fundamental features such as `SessionFactory`, `Session`, and `Criteria` (e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9415513/248082))
- Now, you can perform Unit Testing to verify your method is working properly

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
package com.om39a.spring.training.bean;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ApplicationUtil.class)
public class ApplicationUtilTest {

    private ApplicationUtil applicationUtil;

    @Mock
    SessionFactory mockSessionFactory;

    @Mock
    Session mockSession;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        applicationUtil = PowerMockito.spy(new ApplicationUtil());
    }

    @Test
    public void testApplicationUtil() throws Exception {
        Whitebox.setInternalState("sessionFactory", mockSession);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(applicationUtil, "setSessionFactory");
        Mockito.when(mockSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(
                mockSession);
        applicationUtil.changeSearchEquipementToCriteria(null);
        /* ...
         * ...
         * ...
         * Assert statments goes here 
         * ...
         * ...
         * ...
         */
    }
}
```